# How to structure lookup tables?

Tags: c++, class, lookup-tables

I am implementing lookup tables.

- There should be one index column, which can be `int`, `double`, or `string`. If it is `int` or `double`, when looking up a value, it should lookup which range it falls int (so if the indices are 0, 5, 10, etc, and the lookup value is 9, it should return the content corresponding to index 5). If it's a `string`, it only looks for exact matches.
- The content is one or more columns, each of which may (independently of each other and the index) be `int`, `double`, or `string` as well.
- The data for the tables should exist in a separate file (preferably one for all tables, regardless of type).
- The tables should then be stored in a "semi-dynamic" way (ie, at run-time they will be fix, but I need to be able to update, add or modify the tables between runs).

I figured I need to create a base class of `table`, which go in a `map`, regardless of what they contain and what they return. The key is the name of the `table`, and is read from the file. After that, I'm a bit stumped as to how to proceed.

I first had the idea of creating some sort of `template`, such as `template <class INDEX, class CONTENT, int COL, int ROW>` and then define `array<INDEX>[ROW]` and `array<CONTENT>[COL][ROW]`. But when I tried that, I couldn't put them in the same `map` (because the instantiations are interpreted as different classes and thus incompatible to one type?).

Then I figured I should probably use an inheritance class structure, with the base class in the `map`, and then subclass for each type of table. However, if that's the case, I'd need *a lot* of classes to cover all the combinations of index and content columns being one of the three data types. So I'd need to generalise a bit more, and then I thought "why don't I store all the data as `string` and keep an `array<int>` (or even `enum`?) to keep track of which of the cases each column is (ie `int`, `double`, or `string`)?" That would be a possible solution, as far as I see, although it would be quite ugly and inefficient. Inefficiency isn't a huge problem, since the `tables` aren't going to be that many or that large, so storing `strings` and casting to `int`/`double` when needed would be viable, but I'd like to do it properly anyway. Also, there's the issue of having the `table` class needing all the different versions of `lookup` (ie that takes in and returns `int`, `double`, and/or `string`), so I might end up calling the wrong function on the object (ie call for an `int` when the table consists of text that cannot be cast from `string`.). Again, that's not a huge problem, apart from that it's ugly and probably not the way to do it.

I could also have "empty `arrays`" of each of the type I'm not using, and keep track of which has data with another `array<int>` (or `enum`), and maybe a `map<int, array<TYPE> >`, where `TYPE` is the type of each column, and then figure out based on which column I'm looking for what `array` contains what I have saved/need. But that feels even more convoluted and awkward (but maybe I'm wrong).

Alternatively, I *could*, of course, start splitting up the tables into smaller ones (ie maybe all have one index and only one content column, or even a structure of "index columns" connected to one or more "content columns"). But then I'd need to figure out a neat way of doing that, which I haven't been able to so far.

Anyway, the data file might look like:

```
Age Table
0;Kid
18;Young Adult
30;Middle-Age
65;Retired

Average Living Space Per District
Kid;10;14;12
Young Adult;20;30;35
Middle-Age;30;50;50
Retired;50;60;55

{etc}
```

Does anyone have any hints or advice as to how to tackle this problem?

Comment: From the outside, it looks like all you really want/need is a database of sorts (which you can then query into). Have you looked into this option instead of hand-rolling everything? MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQLite... There's no shortage of options I'd say.

Comment: Why does [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) not work for you?

Comment: Your question is more suitable for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. If you have implemented your solution in code, then you can also try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Your question is probably not a good fit for stackoverflow.com because https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: About `std::map`: it comes with its own [`upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound), it will find the first element greater, and the desired lower value then will be `std::prev(map.upper_bound(age))` (note: there's `lower_bound`, too, giving first element not less, but that will give you bad result for ages exactly matching a boundery).

Comment: There even is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426884/1312382) for how to correctly apply `upper_bound`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I might've been unclear, but it's not that `map`, per see, isn't what I'm looking for, but I'm trying to come up with a data structure that allows me to do what I want. Basically, I tried to create `templates` that allow me to define what I have in my tables (the `value` in my `map`), but it seems that each different kind is incompatible since it's its own class from compilation. It probably is very much useable, but I want to nail down the underlying structure of the data that I use.

Comment: @Aconcagua Great, thanks for the input!

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, I suppose you are correct. I guess the task of tackling SQL in C++ felt quite daunting, but after a bit of searching and trial and error, it doesn't seem that arduous. I'm most familiar with SQLite, so I'll start with that. Thanks!

Comment: @AnthonyKong Apologies. Feel free to delete this post. Although, I couldn't find out exactly where I was out of line with my question, based on your link.

Comment: @GreatName -- gotcha, nothing wrong with that for learning purposes, just understand what you or I may write on the fly won't be nearly as well tested or optimized as using a container library function. That said, I could see a templated implementation of a struct holding a key and  additional struct as members allowing something similar to `std::map`.

Comment: @AnthonyKong when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)